# .Net 6 with NLog not Registering my Custom Render Layout

Tags: c#, nlog

In a .Net 6 Web API using NLog, how can I intercept the posted body so I can manipulate it before logging it?

**Here's what I've got:**

I've got a .Net Framework 4.7.2 Web API with a `DelegatingHandler` to intercept a request's body. I then go through each key and replace the value if the key is in a list of strings. For example: if the key is `Password` or `Pwd` I replace the value with `xxx` so that I can log the full body without security concerns. it's worked very well. I'm trying to replicate this on a .Net 6 Web API Project.

**Here's what I've done:**

I've looked through the [NLog source code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) to see how they get the `aspnet-request-posted-body`. I believe I've got something but I don't see NLog calling/using my `RenderLayout`.

```
[LayoutRenderer("aspnet-request-posted-body-2")]
public class TestRender : AspNetLayoutRendererBase {
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent) {
        var items = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items;
        if (items == null || items.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (items.TryGetValue("aspnet-request-posted-body-2", out var value)) {
            builder.Append(value as string);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Middleware`

```
public class RequestLoggerMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RequestLoggerMiddleware> _logger;

    public RequestLoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RequestLoggerMiddleware> logger) {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        var requestBody = await new HttpContextExtensions().PeekBodyAsync(context);
        var contentType = context.Request.ContentType;

        // Not done yet, but adding this for testing
        switch (contentType) {
            case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
                // Clean data
                ...
                // Add to context
                context.Items.Add("aspnet-request-posted-body-2", requestBody);
                break;
            case "application/*+json":
            case "application/json":
            case "text/json":
                // Clean data
                ...
                // Add to context
                context.Items.Add("aspnet-request-posted-body-2", JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        _logger
            .LogInformation("TESTING");
        
        // With a breakpoint I checked that `content` does have the item listed above
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Here's is my `Program.cs` file

```
var logger = LogManager
            .LoadConfiguration(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Configs/NLog/nlog.config"))
            .Setup()
            .SetupExtensions(x => {
                x.RegisterLayoutRenderer<TestRender>("aspnet-request-posted-body-2");
            })
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("init main");

try {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Register NLog's Request Body Layout
    app.UseMiddleware<NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>();
    // Register my custom layout
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggerMiddleware>();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
} finally {
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: When you store the request-body in the HttpContext.Items-dictionary, then you don't need to register custom layout. Just use `${aspnet-item:aspnet-request-posted-body-2}` in your NLog.config. Maybe consider removing `NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware` since you already have your own `RequestLoggerMiddleware`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-HttpContext-Item-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Btw. if you a missing customizations to `NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware` (Ex. to remove unwanted parts). Then you are wellcome to create a pull-request for https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pulls

Comment: Btw. make sure to hookup  `SetupExtensions` before loading logging-configuration that depends on those extensions. Ex. `LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(...).LoadConfigurationFromFile(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Configs/NLog/nlog.config")`

Comment: @RolfKristensen I was thinking of doing a PR as soon as I get it working well and generalize it for sure. Thanks for the `${aspnet-item:...}`, I'll try that real quick and report my results. I'll also update the `SetupExtensions` as you mentioned.

Comment: @RolfKristensen this worked! Thank you! Can you post an answer so I can accept it? once I get a chance to add my logic to NLog, I'll add a PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store the request-body in the `HttpContext.Items`-dictionary, then you don't need to register custom layout. Just use `${aspnet-item:aspnet-request-posted-body-2}` in your `NLog.config`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-HttpContext-Item-Layout-Renderer

Maybe consider removing `NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware` since you already have your own `RequestLoggerMiddleware`.

Btw. make sure to hookup `SetupExtensions` before loading logging-configuration that depends on those extensions. Ex. `LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(...).LoadConfigurationFromFile(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Configs/NLog/nlog.config")`

Comment: Thanks! it worked! However I have another issue which I may have to post in a different post (let me know if I should). It seems related to adding `HttpContext.Items`. The error I get is `System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too many bytes written (82 of 41).`. Would I have to update the `Content-Length` or is there another method I can use to fix? Thanks.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Sounds like a different problem, as the question is about request-body, and it seems the issue you have now is about response-body.

Comment: thank you. Figured it out. Sloppy `if` statements. All good now!